# Importing pyttsx speech engine on mac (Python 2.7.14)

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to work with the `pyttsx` speech engine on mac, I installed the library with this command:

```
sudo pip install pyttsx.
```

When I try to import the library and running the following code:

```
import pyttsx engine = pyttsx.init() engine.say('...') engine.runAndWait().
```

I get this Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/Lana/Desktop/Zaid/End_Projekt_MakE_YouR_ChoicE_zaid_zaim ON MAC/try.py", line 2, in      engine = pyttsx.init()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx/**init**.py", line 39, in init     eng = Engine(driverName, debug)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx/engine.py", line 45, in **init**     self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx/driver.py", line 64, in **init**     self._module = **import**(name, globals(), locals(), [driverName])   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx/drivers/nsss.py", line 18, in  from Foundation import * ImportError: No module named Foundation.

I dont know what is meant with the Foundation.

Comment: This video may help you[](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPoQTodrpxk) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPoQTodrpxk
Also Check that you imported pyttsx in your python IDLE by writing `python` in the cmd then `import pyttsx`